# De « je suis » à « ch'u » ?

Tags: prononciation, oral, registre-familier, linguistique

> Je suis pas là → Ch'u pas là.

Comment explique-t-on le passage de l'expression *Je suis* à l'expression *Ch'u* ?

... je pense que ça s'écrit *ch'u*, mais je le vois des fois écrit *chu*. Impossible pour moi de trouver l'expression dans un dico en tous les cas. Pourtant tout le monde (il me semble) la connait.

Je peux imaginer qu'on passe de *j* à *ch*… mais alors par quel processus en vient-on à remplacer *ui* par *u* ? Ou alors y a-t-il un processus linguistique complètement différent ? Un raccourci d'enfant ? La faute à [Titeuf](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titeuf) ?

Comment: Je n'ai jamais entendu "ch'u" mais [ʃɥi]. Et de toute façon c'est une prononciation fautive et on ne la trouvera pas dans un dictionnaire.

Comment: Perso, rien ne me surprend et je les emploie tous. *Je ne suis pas*, *je suis pas*, *j'suis pas*, *ch'uis pas*, *ch'u pas*, *ch'pas*… Ok, plus court que ça, ça devient difficile de comprendre.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il s'agit d'un *raccourci de prononciation*. À l'oral, on a tendance à manger des syllabes pour aller plus vite. C'est particulièrement flagrant sur les expressions employées fréquemment, comme "C'est pas" qui devient "C'pas" ou "Je sais" qui devient "J'sais". Dans le cas de "Je suis", voici le cheminement :

> Je suis
>   J'suis

Le "e" est le premier à disparaître. Cette forme est assez populaire, même à l'écrit (dans un registre familier).

> Chuis / Chui / Ch'ui / ...

Le [ʒs] dérive naturellement vers [ʃ], car assez proche et plus facile à prononcer.

> Ch'u / Chu

Sans doute parce que le "i" vient après le "u", ou parce que [ʃu] est plus facile à dire rapidement que [ʃi] (c'est subjectif...), on ne garde que le "u" pour une forme très raccourcie.

> Ch'

Le stade ultime, qui n'est presque plus compréhensible.

> Ch'pas d'accord
>   Ch'malade depuis hier

Concernant la popularité : j'utilise plus la forme "Chui" que "Chu". J'entends également plus de "Chui" que de "Chu", mais cela relève sans doute des parlés locaux. Quant à la forme "Ch'", je l'entends surtout parmi les adolescents (collégiens et compagnie).

Comment: Je pense aussi que la différence à l'oral entre `ch'ui` et `ch'u` est minime. En parlant vite, il n'y a quasiment aucune différence. Le "mot" ne ressemblant à aucun autre, il n'y a pas de confusion possible. Un peu comme `quelque chose` et `kekchose`.

Answer (score 8):

Il y a deux évolutions de prononciation séparées, là : d'un coté la fusion des consonnes initiales de *je* et *suis* ; de l'autre la fusion de la semi-voyelle et de la voyelle de *suis*.

---

Le premier phénomène est -comme tu le mentionnes- facile à expliquer : le schwa de *je* s'élide et le son /ʒ/ devient /ʃ/ par [assimilation régressive](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assimilation_%28phon%C3%A9tique%29#Assimilation_r.C3.A9gressive). Le résultat, ch'suis, débute par un groupe de consonnes difficile à prononcer et est donc simplifié d'abord par la palatalisation de /s/ en /ʃ/ (ch'chuis) puis par la réduction de la consonne double en consonne simple (chuis).

En API (et avec mon accent belge) ça donne :

```
/ʒœswi/ --> */ʒswi/ --> */ʃswi/ --> /ʃ:wi/ --> /ʃwi/
```

C'est un phénomène qui s'applique à tous les verbes qui commence par un s (je sais - chais ; je suivais - ch'chuivais ; je serai - chrai ; je sens - chens et ainsi de suite). Rien d’exceptionnel ici donc.

---

Le passage de *ui* à *u* est beaucoup plus rare et mérite donc explication.

Pour commencer la prononciation chu (/ʃy/) est souvent associée aux Canadiens, mais elle s'entend aussi en France et Belgique (et donc, probablement, en Suisse).

Ensuite, elle n'est limitée à "je suis". Voici les deux autres contextes dans lesquels je l'ai entendue ici, en Belgique :

- Dans des pronoms, par exemple *lui* ("Je lui ai parlé" prononcé "J'u ai parlé") ou celui ("celui-là" prononcé "çu-là")
- Dans les cas à un autre pronom intervient entre je et suis ("Je me suis rappelé" prononcé "Je m'sus rapplé"

Par contre, personne ne semble réduire "j'ai cuit" à "j'ai cu" ou "suivre" à "suvre" (d'ailleurs, "je suis" dans le sens de suivre ne se réduit jamais à chuis ou chu). Il y a donc quelque chose de spécial à propos de "je suis". (j'y reviendrai plus bas)

Il y a trois manières de réduire une combinaison semi-voyelle + voyelle à une simple voyelle :

1. supprimer la voyelle et transformer la semi-voyelle en la voyelle correspondante (/w/ - /u/ ; /ɥ/ - /y/ ; /j/ - /i/). Ce processus fonctionnerait pour les français de France et du Canada, où *suis* est prononcé /sɥi/, ce qui produirait donc bien /sy/ (*su*, qui deviendrait *chu*) par ce mécanisme. Par contre en Belgique, suis est prononcé /swi/, ce qui donnerait */su/ (*sou*, et donc *chou*), contrairement à ce qu'on observe. Ce n'est donc pas la bonne hypothèse.
2. supprimer purement et simplement la semi-voyelle. C'est ce qui se passe en français de France et du Canada quand "puis" devient "pis" ou en français parisien quand "je lui" devient "j'y" (après suppression du schwa et du l). Bien entendu, cela donnerait chi et pas chu dans tous les dialectes du français, donc ce n'est pas non plus la bonne explication.
3. "fusionner" la semi-voyelle et la voyelle. La seule différence entre i et u (/i/ et /y/ en API) est la forme des lèvres, étirées pour i et arrondies pour u. Pour transformer i en u il suffit donc d'un petit changement de prononciation. Et justement, les semi-voyelles /ɥ/ (FR, CA) et /w/ (BE) sont prononcées avec un arrondissement des lèvres. Il est donc tentant en prononçant /ɥi/ ou /wi/ de ne pas étirer ses lèvres pour la voyelle, ce qui donne /ɥy/ et /wy/. Lorsqu'on essaye de prononcer swu (/sɥy/ - /swy/), la semi-voyelle est presque inaudible et peut donc être supprimée sans impact pour la compréhension.

Cette dernière hypothèse me semble être la bonne.

En API l'évolution donne donc

```
/ʒœswi/ --> */ʒswi/ --> */ʃswi/ --> /ʃ:wi/ --> /ʃwi/
/swi/ --> */swy/ --> /sy/
/ʃwi/ --> */ʃwy/ --> /ʃy/
```

Ce qui explique l'évolution de "Je suis" en "Chus"

---

Reste à expliquer pourquoi cette réduction phonologique ne s'applique qu'au verbe être et à des pronoms. Ce n'est pas étonnant en ce qui concerne les pronoms, puisqu'il s'agit de clitiques ou d'affixes, qui sont prompt à ce genre de réduction. Qu'un phénomène ne touche que des mots phonologiquement réduits par nature et le verbe être, mais pas les autres verbes, est plus étonnant.

Deux hypothèses: soit "suis" et les pronoms, par leur plus grande fréquence, préfigurent d'une évolution phonologique future ; soit certaines formes du verbe être sont en train de devenir des clitiques, un peu comme les auxiliaires en anglais (Ch'malade ; T'pas cap ; Ç'ton chien, ça ?, etc.).

Malheureusement, je n'ai pas trouvé d'articles par des linguistes qui traitent de ce dernier phénomène en français, juste des commentaires d'internautes.

---

Pour ce qui est de l'orthographe, il n'y pas de norme, puisque le français normé s'est arrêté au 17ème siècle et la plupart des évolutions subséquentes sont considérées comme fautives (il suffit de lire quelques-uns des commentaires à cette questions dénonçant chuis et chu comme fautifs).

Perso, je préfère chu(s) à ch'u(s) vu qu'au point où on en est, [il est illusoire de considérer je et suis comme deux mots distincts plutôt que deux morphèmes d'un même mot](http://stl.recherche.univ-lille3.fr/sitespersonnels/miller/Miller_Monachesi_clitiques.pdf). Mais je doute fortement que quiconque viennent corriger une forme hors-norme par une autre qui l'est tout autant.

Comment: Très intéressant. Je me permets une question... Je vois que vous avez utilisé la prononciation /ʃwi/. Est-ce ainsi que c'est prononcé en Belgique? Au Québec, on entend surtout /ʃɥi/, qui devient naturellement /ʃy/ lorsqu'on laisse tomber le i final (on pourrait penser à l'énonciation suspendue dès le début du chiffre 8, /ɥit/, qui produirait quelque chose d'assez près du son /y/).

Comment: @Feelew On n'a pas du tout le phonème /ɥ/ en Belgique. D'une manière générale, ce qui est prononcé /ɥi/ dans les autres dialectes du Français est /wi/ en Belgique, et ce qui est prononcé /wi/ est /u.(w)i/ ici. Donc "lui" sonne comme "Louis" et "Louis" a deux syllabes. /ɥɛ̃/ et /wɛ̃/ fusionnent en [wæ̃], donc "juin" et "joint" sont homophones pour moi.

Comment: Merci! Une autre question alors: huit se prononcerait /wit/ en Belgique, si je vous comprends bien?

Comment: @Feelew exactement, oui

Answer (score 1):

Comme *Laure* l'a commenté, l'expression est fautive, et oralement (lorsque l'enfant commence à parler, ou lorsqu'on l'imite intentionnellement) on prononce le ***i***.

Le 'glissé' du *je* vers le *'cheu'* semble naturel, la dégradation de l'articulation du *je* donnant un *[ʃ]*.

Je l'ai *[trouvé](http://www.atoute.org/n/forum/showthread.php?t=165547)* écrit au moins *[deux fois](http://www.auvieuxtreuil.ca/programmation-spectacles-iles-de-la-madeleine/details/307-francine-lareau-ch-u-pas-connue-encore.html)* : cela ressemble beaucoup à un posture 'comique', à une envie de se démarquer en exagérant une expression d'origine enfantine, une sorte de régression symbolique dont je laisse le monde psy débattre.

Cela ne ressemble pas du tout à une évolution grammaticale, mais à une mode passagère, un argot  ultra minoritaire.

Comment: C'est [ʒs] (assez imprononçable sans schwa) qui devient [ʃ], pas [ʒ] tout seul. À moins d'avoir un chat dans la gorge, personne ne dit « che marche ».

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez « che marche » argh! Peut-être un héritage des films de la deuxième guerre ? Il me semble cependant que si la langue 'monte' vers le palais, le *je* se met à chuenter.

Comment: On la trouve aussi dans les bistros et discussions wikipedesques, haut lieu de la culture francophone :-) https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Sp%C3%A9cial%3ARecherche&profile=advanced&search=%22ch%27u%22&fulltext=Search&ns1=1&ns2=1&ns3=1&ns4=1&ns5=1&ns7=1&ns8=1&ns9=1&ns10=1&ns11=1&ns12=1&ns13=1&ns14=1&ns15=1&ns100=1&ns101=1&ns102=1&ns103=1&ns104=1&ns105=1&ns828=1&ns829=1&profile=advanced ... (sans commentaires, hi ! hi ! ) Merci pour votre réponse en tous cas.

Answer (score 1):

Le "Chu" est très utilisé dans le langage oral de type familier, surtout au Québec.

Cependant, il n'y a aucune façon de l'écrire correctement, puisque c'est considéré comme grammaticalement incorrect.

Edit: en cherchant sur d'autres forums, j'ai trouvé la chanson "Lindberg" de Robert Charlevois
([paroles ici](http://www.lyricsmania.com/lindberg_lyrics_robert_charlebois.html))

> Alors **chu** reparti sur Québécair, Transworld, Northern, Eastern, Western pis Pan American!
>   Mais ché pu où **chu** rendu

On dirait bien que j'utilisation en "**chu**" peut bien s'écrire de cette manière!

Comment: C'est du registre populaire, donc dépendant du contexte, ça peut être considéré grammaticalement correct.

Comment: Je vous remercie pour votre réponse, qui témoigne de l'usage de cette expression. Cependant, je n'ai pas demandé si elle était correcte ou pas correcte, mais comment est-ce qu'on en vient à la dire ?