# Omitting 'suis' in spoken French

Tags: argot

I was watching Haneke's Time of the Wolf last night. Frequently, I couldn't hear the 'suis' in sentences where I would expect it to occur. Unhelpfully, I cannot remember a specific example, but perhaps someone said what sounded like 'Je fatigué'. Is this just my bad hearing, or slang, or is something else going on?

Comment: Était-il complètement absent ('Je fatigué') ou bien à moitié avalé ('Chuis fatigué') ?

Comment: I guess what you heard is more of a "chuis (fatigué)" that may have sounded like "Je (fatigué)" too, as Mathieu mentionned above. This is very common and both ways may come pretty close when said rather fast.

Comment: Thanks both - you're probably right; unfortunately, it's really not worth watching the film to make sure. :-(

Comment: Duplicate of [De « je suis » à « ch'u » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9545/de-je-suis-%c3%a0-chu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different way to say it in french, if we use *Je suis fatigué.* as default

We have few others informal way to say it:

> Je fatigue.
>
> J'suis fatigué.
>
> Jsuis fatigué.
>
> Chuis fatigué.
>
> Ch'u fatigué.
>
> Ch'fatigué.

*please note that these are familiar and often not correct while writing, they are more used for example when speaking to a close friend or a family member*

Comment: The problem is that Strawberry can't hear any of these forms ; "suis" is completely missing, says that person. Do people shorten the form  further and say "Che fatigué"? I've never heard that.

Comment: Thank you I just updated my answer but I didn't realise that the question was so unclear.

Comment: You are missing *Ch'u fatigué* and even *Ch'fatigué* which is what the OP heard. This was already discussed, although in French.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I updated the answer.