# D'où vient ce T de liaison? → Je suis à l'heure > Ch't'à l'heure

Tags: oral, québec, liaisons

En théorie :

- Je suis allé.
- Tu es inquiète.

À l'oral (au moins au Québec) :

- Ch't'allé.     [ʃta.le]
- T'é (t)inquiète.     [te.tẽ.kjɛt]

L'existence d'un contraste entre la langue orale et celle écrite est immémorial, et certains traits, particularités et irrégularités de la langue parlée sont certainement à peu près inexplicables.

La langue orale pose des défis particuliers: on doit composer son discours sur le vif, ce qui le charge très souvent d'erreurs (plus ou moins fréquentes selon le locuteur ou le temps de préparation), de constructions qui changent soudainement de direction pour diverses raisons, de termes inventés en un instant ou en un très court laps de temps pour des concepts qui émergent et requiert une désignation immédiate. Des jeux de mots ou de l'humour involontaire peuvent introduire des expressions qui vivront un temps dans un cercle plus ou moins étendu.

Parmi les processus à l'œuvre dans la dynamique éloignant la langue orale de la langue écrite, les fausses liaisons sont assez communes (cf. l'étymologie du terme [*pataquès*](https://cnrtl.fr/etymologie/pataqu%C3%A8s)), et certaines reçoivent parfois leur absolution (par exemple le [*-t- euphonique*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=2513)) plus tard dans l'histoire de la langue.

Je suis assez *(ch't'assez)* curieux de connaître l'origine de ce T entre la conjugaison du verbe être aux première et deuxième personnes du singulier et le mot suivant lorsqu'il commence par une voyelle. La connaît-on ? Fausse liaison ? T du verbe être, retiré de ces conjugaisons en particulier, mais remis en place par le génie populaire, voire maintenu d'une conjugaison ancienne ? Autre chose ?

<sub>Une autre question sur ce site, sur un sujet similaire, pour les curieux que ça pourrait intéresser : [De « je suis » à « ch'u »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9545/de-je-suis-%c3%a0-chu)</sub>

Answer (score 8):

L'usage incorrect d'un T au lieu d'un Z de liaison est appelé *cuir* (l'inverse est un *velours*). "Pataquès" est le nom du phénomène dans son ensemble.

Ici, le -t- apparaît  pour **les mêmes raisons que le T euphonique**. En effet, ces constructions **ne permettent pas la liaison** du tout, on ne peut donc pas avoir l’erreur de liaison que définit le pataquès. *Je suis allé* permettant la liaison, ce n'est pas cette forme qui devient directement *ch't'allé*, mais bien l'intermédiaire (typiquement québécois) *Chu allé*, avec l'hiatus problématique. Même phénomène avec la formation *T'es inquiète*, car le français ne permet pas du tout la liaison en -z- après cette forme du verbe *être*.

Ce ne sont dont pas de vrais pataquès, mais des hiatus apparaissant dans des phrases que les gens prononcent réellement, plutôt que dans une construction aujourd'hui presque entièrement restreinte à l'écrit. Leur résolution passe par un phénomène naturel de la langue.

Comment: Oui, un [phonème éphelcystique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phon%C3%A8me_%C3%A9phelcystique) ! ;-)

Comment: @jiliagre Wow, voilà bien un terme que je connaissait absolument pas.

Comment: Moi non plus ! Je l'ai trouvé après avoir fait des recherches suite à ta réponse. J'étais à côté de la plaque (ou *dans les patates* ;-) ) car, je pensais que ce T venait d'un *tu* proche de celui qu'on entend dans les questions québécoises comme *T'es tu allé à Québec ?*

Comment: @jlliagre Ce *tu* est une particule interrogative, qui se cantonne habituellement hors du registre de l'affirmation solide.

Comment: C'est très intéressant comme hypothèse. Je me demanderais tout de même pourquoi le verbe avoir n'aurait pas provoqué le même phénomène pour des hiatus similaires: *j'ai assez, j'ai été, j'ai eu, j'ai inquiété, j'ai obtenu, t'as été, t'as honte, t'as humé, etc.*

Comment: @Pasunclue C'est en effet une question pertinente. Je me demande si le -t- est question n'est pas associé d'une façon ou d'une autre à certaines voyelles précises. Si j'étais linguiste, ce serait une question à creuser...

Comment: Est-ce que la liaison en /z/ est commune après êtes au Québec? Si non, c'est juste une généralisation de la voyelle de liaison de la 3ème personne à toutes les formes de être qui ne terminent par une voyelle, ce qui n'est pas très surprenant et explique pourquoi avoir n'a pas le même comportement

Comment: Pourrais-tu svp me donner davantage une idée de ce que tu veux dire par « leur résolution passe par un phénomène naturel de la langue ». Dans le sens que c'est organique ? C'est emploi du t qui est un phénomène naturel ? As-tu une idée généralement depuis quand à peu près au Québec on dit _chu_ et _ch't'à_ etc. ? Pourquoi en Belgique par exemple ça n'est pas apparu (que je sache) ?

Comment: @escarlateadamantine "Dans le sens que c'est organique ? C'est emploi du t qui est un phénomène naturel ?" Oui, du moins c'est mon opinion. La théorie de Wikipédia qui étend l'usage à partir de verbes comme "fait" ne vient _pas_ de Grevisse, mais ce dernier date l'origine du -t- de liaison au 15e siècle (moyen français, donc). Grevisse est aussi d’opinion que cet usage n'est "normal" qu`'en présence d'un proton inversé et attribue son extension à la langue "populaire ou relâchée".

Comment: Par contre demander "Pourquoi en Belgique par exemple ça n'est pas apparu"—la réponse étant tout simplement que les [Belges préserve le i](https://www.cathobel.be/2015/07/chuis-pas-ta-mere-mais/) et n'abrège dont pas au point de réduire au seul _ch_—revient réellement à demander "pourquoi les langues on des dialectes qui sont différents" et là on est presque hors-sujet en ce qui me concerne.

Comment: @Circeus Merci pour l'information. Ouais, je parlais des Belges parce que j'ai observé que pour certains trucs ils se rapprochent du Québec parfois, mais ça relève de l'observation bien générique comme je n'ai aucune expertise. Parfois au LBU dans une note on parle des deux variétés et je me pose des questions etc.

Answer (score 0):

On peut supposer, de façon synchronique, que la forme sous-jacente du verbe est *je sut* et que le *t* apparaît comme consonne de liaison. Lorsque le *t* est prononcé, le *u* peut chuter.

Il y a d'autres cas où le français québécois peut présenter des consonnes de liaison différentes du français de référence. Par exemple, on a un *l* de liaison dans *ça a* prononcé [salɑ]. Le pronom *a* ("elle") est prononcé *al* devant une voyelle.

Comment: Est-ce qu'il y a des sources pour l'étymologie de *je sut* du verbe être ?

Comment: @livresque L'émergence d'une forme ?« je sut » me paraît très improbable. En latin, c'est *sum*. En ancien français, le /m/ final s'est transformé en /i/ avec des variations au fil du temps ou des régions. https://micmap.org/dicfro/search/tableaux-de-conjugaison/estre cite 13 orthographes différentes, soit avec une consonne finale prononcée /s/ ou /z/, soit sans consomme finale, mais jamais /t/. Il ne me vient pas à l'esprit de transformation en /t/ à cette époque, et un /t/ serait étrange pour une première personne du singulier.

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' Tout à fait d'accord, c'est pour ça que j'ai du mal à comprendre la réponse, surtout pour une première personne du singulier basée sur sum/esse.  Anonymous pourrais-tu expliquer ?

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' J'ai bien dit que la base de ma proposition était synchronique. Ça veut dire que je m'appuie uniquement sur l'état actuel de la langue, et j'affirme qu'une forme *je sut* permettrait d'expliquer ce qu'on observe effectivement en français québécois familier (*je suis* [ʃy] *perdu*, *je suis allé* [ʃtale]). Donc une objection à mon argument ne peut pas être fondée sur l'étymologie. Il faudrait qu'elle s'appuie sur des observations actuelles de la langue non conformes à la proposition.

Comment: Si la question est de savoir d'où proviendrait la forme [sy(t)], où je mets le *t* entre parenthèses pour indiquer qu'il se prononce devant une voyelle uniquement, il me semble qu'un processus d'analogie avec les formes de la troisième personne du singulier (comme *il est* [je(t)]) suffit pour l'expliquer. En français québécois, une voyelle haute comme [y] se dévoise normalement entre consonnes sourdes, donc il ne reste qu'un petit pas pour passer à [ʃt] devant voyelle.

Comment: @Anonymous Pour une langue qui a un corpus écrit conséquent, une telle hypothèse synchronique qui n'est absolument pas attestée n'est pas plausible.

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' Il est question ici du français québécois familier, pas autre chose. Je serais étonné que les prononciations [ʃy] et [ʃt] ne soient pas très bien attestées. Il faudrait que vous expliquiez quelles données du français québécois familier, qui est évidemment principalement oral, vous trouvez incompatibles avec l'hypothèse.

Comment: Ah, d'accord, je n'avais pas compris que tu postulais une évolution récente pas encore attesté par l'orthographe. Mais là encore, je ne vois pas en quoi cette hypothèse serait plausible. Une forme en -t pour la première personne du singulier ? Et qui n'apparaît que pour certains verbes ? Est-ce que les personnes qui l'utilisent ne font jamais une liaison en [z] ?

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' On rencontre une difficulté ici, car le français québécois familier entre évidemment en concurrence avec la norme (des médias, etc.), où on entend certainement [ʒəsɥi(z)]. Pour distinguer vraiment ce qui relève de l'influence de la norme et les variantes authentiques, il faudrait bien connaître les milieux peu scolarisés en français, ce qui veut dire essentiellement aujourd'hui les milieux francophones ruraux et populaires au Canada hors Québec. Mon intuition me dit que [ʃyz] doit être pratiquement inexistant, étant un cas hybride entre le québécois et la norme...

Comment: mais mon intuition est celle d'un anglophone ayant une connaissance bonne mais moins approfondie du franco-québécois que celle de mes compatriotes francophones. On ne verra jamais l'orthographe *je sut* car quand on transcrit les prononciations non-standard (*chu*, *ch't*), on le fait pour transcrire directement ce qu'on entend, pas pour rétablir les phonèmes sous-jacents!

Comment: Concernant pourquoi ça n'apparaît que pour certains verbes. il y a vraiment très peu de verbes où on fait la liaison en français québécois familier. Il faudrait voir, mais je trouverais plausible que dans les milieux peu touchés par la norme, ce soit limité aux formes monosyllabiques des verbes *être* et *avoir*.