# What does "j't'a" mean?

Tags: sens, québec, paroles-de-chanson, auxiliaires, euphonie

I have several guesses. Does it mean "j'étais à", "j'ai été à", or does the "t" here mean "you"?

> Demain soir j't'a Montmagny

It is [in a song](https://lyricstranslate.com/fr/les-cowboys-fringants-lam%C3%A9rique-pleure-lyrics.html) by *les Cowboys fringants*.

Comment: @None I made an edit to the post. The context is "Demain soir j't'a Montmagny"

Comment: It can't be *j'étais à* or *j'ai été à* since we have *demain*. Thanks to your addition I could find this was a line from a song by *Les cowboys fringants* so I suppose this is a quebecism. I could make a guess on *j'irai à Montmagny* or *je serai à* but one of the Canadian French on the site will answer without any hesitation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is simply *je suis à Montmagny* i.e. "I'm in Montmagny", with the present tense used for a future event (I'll be in...). In the version of the lyrics you presented, the *à* is missing its diacritic. Consider this version:

> [*Demain soir ch’t’à Montmagny*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sYRp8oP0yiw) [in *L'Amérique pleure*, [Les Cowboys fringants](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Cowboys_fringants)]

This is the same as *j't'à*. In Québec spoken French, you may find these reductions with the verb [*être*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois#%C3%8Atre). When you have the first person singular, *je suis*, followed by a vowel, you'll find this (phonetic) *t* inserted in between the pronoun and the verb in the reduction; it has no grammatical value (more generally, using a consonant like *t* has been known to be a [way to avoid](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=2514) a pause between syllables in other cases).

In any case, when you pronounce *je suis à*, you can make the liaison between the verb and the preposition *à*, but it's [not mandatory](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3550) that I know of, or rather pause. In Québec spoken French, you may have this different, shorter and maybe easier to pronounce variation. It's not something you would formally write except when you want to showcase the spoken language. When I read *je suis à Montmagny*, as a native speaker of the variety, I might end up pronouncing it exactly like in the lyrics from the song, depending on context, irrespective of the spelling.

---

Il s'agit simplement de *je suis à Montmagny*, avec le présent utilisé pour un événement futur (*je serai à...*). Dans la version des paroles présentée en question, il manque l'accent sur à. Voir plutôt celle-ci :

> [*Demain soir ch’t’à Montmagny*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sYRp8oP0yiw) [dans *L'Amérique pleure*, [Les Cowboys fringants](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Cowboys_fringants)]

C'est la même chose que *j't'à*. En français parlé québécois, on peut trouver ces réductions avec le verbe [*être*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois#%C3%8Atre). Lorsqu'on a la première personne du singulier suivie d'une voyelle, on a ce *t* (phonétique) intercalé entre le pronom et le verbe dans la réduction ; il n'a aucune valeur grammaticale (plus généralement, l'utilisation d'une consonne comme le *t* est un moyen possible d'éviter le [hiatus](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=2514) entre les syllabes dans d'autres cas).

Quoiqu'il en soit, quand on prononce *je suis à*, on peut faire la liaison entre le verbe et la préposition *à*, mais ce n'est [pas obligatoire](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3550) à ma connaissance, ou faire une pause. En français parlé québécois, on peut avoir cette façon différente de s'exprimer, plus courte et peut-être plus facile à prononcer. Ce n'est pas quelque chose qu'on écrirait formellement, sauf quand on veut mettre en valeur la langue parlée. Quand je lis *je suis à Montmagny*, en tant que locuteur natif de la variété, je pourrais finir par le prononcer exactement comme dans les paroles de la chanson, selon le contexte, indépendamment de l'orthographe.

Comment: Est-ce que c'est vraiment un _t euphonique_ ? Pourquoi on a ça au Québec déjà ? Je pense pouvoir aussi prononcer _jchua_, pourquoi et comment ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128055/discussion-between-escarlate-adamantine-and-lambie).

Comment: que cela plaise ou pas, c,est clairement le même phonème que [discuté ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/42285). La question de savoir si c'est "prononçable" n'est pas pertinente: si elle l'était, les anglophone prononcerait les /p/ dans *psychology* ou *pterodactyl*!

Comment: @Circeus Merci, j'avais pas vu cette Q&A passer, mais je me souviens étrangement maintenant de ta réponse à cause du mot _cuir_...